# ListView with a TextEdit header messes up

Tags: android

I have a ListView, and I have added a header (with getListView().addHeaderView) that simply contains a TextEdit widget.

[image]

Then when I tap the TextEdit to start writting, the keyboard appears and it messes up the list!
[image]

If I tap everywhere else to hide the keyboard, the list messes up again!

I don't know why is this happening. I thought it was something related with the onConfigurationChanged method, but after implementing it (and adding the corresponding attribute in the manifest file) the problem persists.

How could I fix it? Why is Android messing up my list?

**EDIT:**

My list uses a custom adapter, this is the getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v != null) {
        return v;
    }

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    ListTask list_item = items.get(position);

    if (list_item != null) {
        TextView item_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        item_name.setText(list_item.getTitle());
    }

    return v;
}
```

The problem is not the value of my items, but their order. They are displayed in a different order when the keyboard appears, but the values are correct.

**EDIT2:**

Ok, I have changed my getView method with rekaszeru's suggestion and now it works as expected. But now I'm facing another problem: **what if my items have two textviews?**

Let's say the second textview is optional, and "Item 1" and "Item 3" have it, but "Item 2" does not, so it's initialized as a void String (length == 0).
The first time the list is displayed, it shows "Item1" and "Item 3" with their second textview, and "Item 2" without it. That's correct. But when the keyboard appears, the "Item 2" takes the second textview of another item and displays it!

This is the modified code I have right now:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }

    ListTask list_item = items.get(position);

    TextView item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView item_optional_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_optional_text);

    item_name.setText(list_item.getTitle());

    // if the item has defined the optional text, make some room and display it
    if (item_optional_text.isNotEmpty()) {
        LayoutParams layout_params = (LayoutParams) item_name.getLayoutParams();
        layout_params.topMargin = 10;
        layout_params.height = -2;  // -2: wrap_content
        item_name.setLayoutParams(layout_params);
        item_optional_text.setText(list_item.getOptionalText());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

The isNotEmpty() does this in the Item class:

```
public boolean isNotEmpty() {
    return this.optional_text.length() > 0;
}
```

Maybe it's too complex to understand in a written question. If so, I can make a short video showing the problem and my source code. Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: Does this still happens if the EditText is not a header view of the list ?

Comment: The problem is in your adapter and row recycling, in all likelihood. Assuming that you are using a custom Adapter implementation, temporarily substitute a plain Adapter (e.g., ArrayAdapter if that's what you were subclassing). If the problem goes away, it's definitely with your custom adapter's row recycling logic.

Comment: @CommonsWare: yes, I use a custom adapter, I have edited my question with the contents of the getView method. Why is Android changing the order of my items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the `getView` method in your `ListAdapter` implementation, and make sure that you always assign a new value to the view that you are returning (or at least always update it to contain the proper data).

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    //set the necessary data in your TextViews, Checkboxes, etc...
    return convertView;
}
```

If you don't inflate your item renderer, then you can instantiate it from code, like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
        convertView = new TextView([...]);
        convertView.setText(textBasedOnYourData);
        return convertView;
}
```

**Edit**
As @CommonsWare noted, attention should be payed to the recycling of your list item renderer. So instead of instantiating it every time, you should check whether it already exists or not, and update the underlying `TextView` afterwards.

So I'd suggest give a try to this slightly modified `getView` implementation:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }

    ListTask list_item = items.get(position);
    TextView item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    //the item should never be null, but just in case: 
    item_name.setText((list_item == null) ? "" : list_item.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: @rekaszeru: Don't forget that the OP needs to pay attention to the `convertView` parameter, for row recycling.

Comment: I don't understand what should I do... the value of my items is not changed, but just their order. I have added more info to my question with the contents of the getView method.

Comment: Please see my update, and consider giving it a try. This method is called every time the layout needs to be redrawn, regardless of your items' data have changed or not.

Comment: Your slightly modified `getView` has the same problem as the OPs - you should NOT be checking `if (list_item != null)` - you should be setting the text EVERY time. If `list_item` is null then you may want to change the text of the item to say `no item` or something - but everytime `getView` is called you need to update your row UI.

Comment: You're right, i was focusing too much on not to return the `convertView` right away if it's not null, that I passed the rest of that code. Updated though, to do what i wrote it should in the pretext of the method.

Comment: Thanks rekaszeru, I've applied your suggestion and I got it working :) But I'm facing a new and related problem with this, see my Edit2 in my question... how difficult are ListView at the beginning!

Comment: There won't be any problem using 2 or more textviews or any other (event interactive) view. You just include it in your `list_row.xml`. And the solution to your problem is the same as before: you set the text for `item_optional_text` anyway, no matter what: remove the `item_optional_text.setText(...` from the `if (item_optional_text.isNotEmpty())` clause, and put it after: `item_optional_text.setText(list_item.getOptionalText() == null ? "" : list_item.getOptionalText());`

Comment: Yes, but although I put the setText after the if, the contents from within the if clause are being executed anyway. I don't want them to be executed if the optional_text is void...

Comment: Then you should check for that, not for the renderer whether contains anything or not. Change your if clouse to `if (list_item.getOptionalText() != null)` and it will work.

Comment: Mmmm... tried it, but it doesn't solve the problem entirely. I have uploaded a simple Android app to github here: https://gist.github.com/fc545489701344b84006  As you can see, the "Item 2" goes up in the row when you tap the EditText (it's what the if does), but ALSO gives the optional text a void value (it's what the "else" clause does)... do you know why is this happening?

Comment: i can't see any else clauses... but i assume that you set the value of the optionalText to be the one that you enter into the editText, and that's why.

Comment: It's in the CustomListAdapter.java, line 44

Comment: I'll place this new problem in a different question, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your row recycling is messed up. Android is not changing the order of the items, you are.

Right now, if you are passed a row to recycle, you return it without modification. This is a mistake. You are supposed to modify the contents of the row to reflect the data at the supplied position. The only piece of logic you can skip in this case is inflating a brand-new row.

[Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that goes through all of this.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at your excerpt, although I don't understand your answer. My rows are not modified at all...

Comment: @David: You are returning the view if it isn't null, and therefore you are not setting any text to your `TextView`.

Comment: @David: 2 simple rules for view recycling: 1) Only inflate if `convertView` is null, reuse `convertView` otherwise; and 2) EVERY time `getView` is called update the view. So if `list_item` is null you should set the text to be "No item" otherwise the row will display the text it had previously.

Comment: @David: `getView()` is called many times, even for rows you think you did before. That will occur due to scrolling or other events that "invalidate" the `ListView`. Hence, as @Joseph Earl indicates, you must populate your row *every* time `getView()` is called. The only step you can skip is inflating the row, if there is a row to recycle.

Comment: @CommonsWare & @Joseph: thanks for the clarification, now I understand it better :)  I'm facing a new and related problem though, I have updated my question... I've tried to apply the knowdledge I'm acquiring from you to fix it, but I'm unable to notice where is the problem now...

Comment: @David: You have to change *all* widgets *every* call to `getView()`. Not some widgets. Not some calls to `getView()`. Every widget. Every call. IOW, once you get past determining whether you are recycling a row or not, every `if` needs an `else`. In your case, your `if (item_optional_text.isNotEmpty())` has to have an `else` where you fix up a row that previously had gone through the `if` path.

Comment: @David: At this point, I can't help you. Use your debugger (if you're using Eclipse) or `Log` statements (if not) to determine what is going on.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Ok, I've added an else clause with just this line: item_optional_text.setText(""), but the content of the if clause are also executed. Reading your comments I assume this is normal. So, in the case of row recycle, both the if and the else are executed? In my example, the if is making changes to the layout... so, must I rollback those changes in the else? (there is double processing for each row then, I think it's a waste of performance).

Comment: @David: "Reading your comments I assume this is normal." -- it is impossible for both the `if` and the `else` paths of the same `if-else `statement to be executed, in Java or any other programming language. "In my example, the if is making changes to the layout... so, must I rollback those changes in the else?" -- your job is to return a `View` from `getView()` that is completely correct, and in the case of recycling, that has to take into account whatever you might have done previously to the row. How you achieve that is up to you.

Comment: I have uploaded to github a little Android app that illustrates this problem, I don't know what more I can try...: https://gist.github.com/fc545489701344b84006  As you can see, the "Item 2" goes up in the row when you tap the EditText (it's what the if does), but ALSO gives the optional text a void value (it's what the "else" clause does)... do you know why is this happening?

Comment: I'll place this new problem in a different question, thanks for your help.